# Xamarin ios DNS resolving to public ip

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurlconnection

We are building a ios app using xamarin and modernhttpclient. To access our server we are using the per app vpn option. When the app starts I can see the tunnel start but when the first api call goes out it is sending it to the public ip address and not the internal one.

I have tried to test to ensure the tunnel is started before the app and I still get the public IP of the host I am trying to hit. Any way to force the app to use our internal dns or clear the dns cache before making my rest call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the tunnel traffic failing to find the dns servers and failing over to cell dns